# How Do I Change The View Of My Gnuplot 3d Heatmap and view slices or planes of it?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, heatmap

Im new to gnuplot and my 3d heatmap is being shown from the angle of the attached image. Is there a command to change the view to look from a different axis? Also is there a way to create slices of of the 3d heatmap where I am able to plot it at a xz plane? [current heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Ogn.png)

I have tried set view map but am unsure how the command works exactly and cant seem to change the view.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Without having your script and without knowing how your data looks like it's difficult to help. Have you checked `help view`? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example